# How delete the oldest child node after entering a new child node in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

After adding 10 child I want to delete the first child whenever a new child added in the database.

Comment: I think it is firebase. Is it true?

Comment: yes its firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you

```
rootref.child("messeges").child(YourInnerChildKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      int count = 0;
      String firstNodeId;
      for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (count == 0) firstNodeId = ds.getKey();
        count++;
      }

      if(count > 10){
         rootref.child("messeges").child(YourInnerChildKey).removeEventListener(this);
         firebase.child(firstNodeId).removeValue();
         rootref.child("messeges").child(YourInnerChildKey).addValueEventListener(this);
      }
}
```

Comment: you have to get key of the node which you want to delete.

Comment: initilize it with null `String firstNodeId = null` and also check if it is null or not with count `if(count > 10 && firstNodeId != null)`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the firebase cloud functions. Cloud functions is like are triggers ready to perform a certain task, such as when an item is created, added, deleted or updated, and much more.

Read about it on:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started